# Every complex polynomial is a product of first degree polynomials, alternative proofs?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, alternative-proof

> **Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.** Every non-constant single-variable polynomial with complex coefficients has at least one complex root.

Using the this we can easily show the result with successive divisions, my question is, are there any other ways to prove it?

Comment: This isn't a way to prove it, it is an equivalent statement.

Comment: So if you're asking how to prove that, that is a giant can of worms. Notoriously, there's no known algebraic proof. All of them involve at least some analysis or topology.

Comment: Have a look at Hatchers [Algebraic Topology](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) page $31$.

Comment: [Relevant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10535/ways-to-prove-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra)

Comment: I'm sorry, but those proofs aren't exactly elementary for me, as my toolbox is pretty limited. Also, I'm not interested in proving the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, but the result show in title instead.

Comment: I believe the question is about this result: **if every polynomial has at least one root, then every polynomial splits completely** .  The OP wants to prove it by a method other than successive divisions of polynomials.

Comment: @FuzzyPixelz But you need the fundamental theorem of algebra to prove the claim in the title.

Comment: If so, is there another way to do it ?

Comment: @MattSamuel What do you mean, there's no known algebraic proof? It can be proven algebraically from the fact that any odd-degree polynomial with real coefficients has a real root. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra#Algebraic_proofs

Comment: @Akiva And how is that critical fact proved? Analysis.

Comment: @MattSamuel If that's your criterion, then in fact no purely algebraic proof is _possible_. You can't even prove that $x^5-x+1$ (for example) has any roots, purely algebraically.

Comment: @MattSamuel I agree. Without any analysis, the theorem cannot be proven.

Comment: @Akiva It's not clear that no algebraic proof is possible. But I'm not the only one who says none is currently known.

Comment: @FuzzyPixelz If you mean an "easy" proof, no. Because proving your statement also means proving the fundamental theorem of arithmetics.

Comment: If you would like, all I'm trying to find is a different path from the FTA (or any other elementary fact about polynomials), to the property stated in the title.

Comment: If you've proven that your complex polynomial $a_nx^n+\dotsb+a_1x+a_0$ is a product of first degree polynomials $(x-z_0)(x-z_1)\dotsb(x-z_n)$, then each $z_i$ is a root of your polynomial. As a result, any proof of the property in your title doubles as a proof of the FTA.

Comment: How does that relate to the question... The aim is not to prove the FTA, it's what I'm assuming, in order to prove the property. Please.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted a way to show that it's true without using the FTA. So you just want to show that it's true without using successive divisions? (Incidentally—but apparently unrelatedly—the [winding number proof](https://youtu.be/0-c4pxa9lBY) of the FTA is quite nice, and I recommend checking it out if you haven't seen it already.)

Comment: I don't know any way of doing this without successive divisions. I also don't know why you'd want to find such a way, to be honest. If you already assume the FTA then it seems like the most direct path.

Comment: Exactly, it's just an assignment, and yes it stresses on the *two* methods. I realize the real hassle is in proving the FTA but I don't know of any topology or complex analysis or any advanced algebra for that matter...

Comment: Maybe use induction on the degree of the polynomial? Of course, this is equivalent to successive division, just phrased differently.